# Spaceship artificial gravity synchronization

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

Probably you remember the scene from "2001, Space Odyssey", where a small shuttle flies to low Earth orbit to reach a giant, ring-shaped mothership that rotates to generate artificial gravity, while the Blue Danube waltz sounds in the background.

So, it is straightforward that a mothership that size would simulate earth's gravity fairly with a rotating period of probably >1 min, as it depends on the radius. My question is: the small shuttle needs to rotate synchronized at the same pace when it docks to the center (the rod) of the mothership. Would astronauts feel any artificial gravity inside their shuttle for rotating at that angular speed, with their much much lesser radius of rotation?

Comment: There would be a small artificial gravity, pulling at their fingertips, but none at the centre of their ship, on the axis of rotation. The apparent force scales with radius (for a fixed angular velocity, as in this case).

Comment: It's a simple calculation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force. The magnitude of the force that you'd feel is proportional to your distance from the axis of rotation.  The shuttle in the movie was much smaller than the outer ring of the space station. The force that the passengers would feel would be proportionately smaller than the force felt by the hotel guests in the outer ring.